# Unable to set IPython default login shell

Tags: ipython

I installed IPython to my Mac by MacPorts. I can run it by *$ IPython*, by not as a login shell.

I have tried to find IPython's directory, which I could then put to my terminal's settings, unsuccessfully by

```
locate /*IPython
```

I did not manage to find it even by whereis.

**How can you set IPython the default login shell?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

locate is not a live database so I'm not surprised that it can't find IPython assuming you just installed it

How did you install, IPython? There must be documentation with the package about the install location?

If you have installed it using macports then look in your macports directory (usually /opt/)

If it is `/opt/` then look in `/opt/local/bin` for your python installation

Comment: @hhafez: I installed IPython by MacPorts.

Comment: @hhafez: I found the installation at /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/python/py26-ipython. I put it to my shell, but each time I open terminal I get the message "Process Completed",

Comment: that file is a port file (describes how macports installed) but it isn't the installation of ipython have a look in /opt/local/bin

Comment: @hhafez:  It is not in /opt/local/bin. I have not found iPython's installation location by Google.